# Navbar expanding bug

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I got this weird bug on my navbar when it expands. It seems like it overlays one of the listed elements, in this case,  home element.

It would be really nice if I could manage to make it expand below the navbar, like in the example named proper navbar.

Here is my code for my navbar:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-collapse">

    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top ">
        <div class = "container">
            <div class="navbar-header">

              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Møllaren Café</a>
                  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">

                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>

                  </button>
            </div>

          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
             <ul class = "nav navbar-nav">
                <li class = "active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Meny</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Om oss</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
              </ul>
              </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-collapse">

    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top ">
        <div class = "container">
            <div class="navbar-header">

              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Møllaren Café</a>
                  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">

                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>

                  </button>
            </div>


          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
             <ul class = "nav navbar-nav">
                <li class = "active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Meny</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Om oss</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
              </ul>
              </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is my font css for the logo. Perhaps this is where the issue is?

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Diploma Regular';
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
src: local('Diploma Regular'), url('Diploma.woff') format('woff');
}

.navbar-brand{
    font-family: 'Diploma Regular';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: local('Diploma Regular'), url('Diploma.woff') format('woff');
}
```

[Navbar bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2w1EM.png)

[Proper navbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6uQL.png)

Comment: Please include the applicable CSS definitions for the displayed HTML.

Comment: I'm sure your CSS causes the bug, because without it, it works properly: https://jsfiddle.net/juzraai/z2grdprL/

Comment: @JohnH I uploaded it now!

Comment: What Bootstrap version do you use? V4 or V3.3.7?

Comment: @Steven I use 3.3.7

Answer (score 0):

Not able to find any issue. check below snippet it works absolutely fine.

```css
.navbar .navbar-nav li a:hover {
  color: #be1d2c;
  trans ition: color .3s;
}

.navbar-header {
  height: 65px;
  padding-top: 0;
}

.navbar-brand {
  font-size: 2.5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-collapse">

  <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top ">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">

        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Møllaren Café</a>
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">

                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>

                  </button>
      </div>


      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Meny</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Om oss</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: May I ask which webbrowser you use? I use chrome and mine does not give the same result as you just showed me.

Comment: am also using chrome only. check bootstrap version you are using!

Comment: I also looked at it in Chrome. No problems with even in Firefox

Comment: am not sure what causes the difference. check on all js and css versions once again.

Comment: @RaJeshRiJo Can you link the ones you are using please?

Comment: @stAMy check on the snippet. you can get it from there itself.

Comment: @RaJeshRiJo But I already use that one. They dont work for me.. I dont get why. Exactly same

Comment: @stAMy even snippet on my answer not working on your machine?

Comment: @RaJeshRiJo Its working on snippet, but not in chrome when i copy paste into my editor.

Comment: @stAMy then try to create a fiddler and check and share it.

Comment: @RaJeshRiJo I found out why! My container div says: .container {
  display : flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

I made that to center my text in navbar, but it ruined my navbar scaling it seems. Problem is now if I remove it, the text is no longer centered.